# BeautifulSoup find div is returning the entire page and not a single element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the company description from this page: https://angel.co/company/sensor-tower but BeautifulSoup is returning the entire text of the page.

I've tried `desc = soup.find('div', class_="content").get_text().strip()` which has worked for other pages on the site but is returning all text on this page.

Expected output should be:

```
Sensor Tower is a comprehensive mobile market intelligence platform that delivers crucial insights into the global app economy. Our flagship Store Intelligence product is an enterprise level offering that provides high-accuracy, worldwide app download and revenue estimates for Apple's App Store and Google Play.

Our best-of-class research interface, which seamlessly integrates across our Store Intelligence, Ad Intelligence, and App Intelligence products, is utilized by executives and analysts alike to drive key business decisions. Our products are counted on by the app world's largest publishers, Fortune 500 companies, and financial institutions to surface emerging market trends, benchmark performance, and grow app businesses at enterprise scale.
```

Comment: It seems that the class `content` is not in the initial source code but it's generated. So you'll have to use something else, like a headless browser, instead of BeautifulSoup.

Comment: No, it's there in the HTTP response from the server, it's not being added dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `div` tags on that page with the class `content`. One of them (line 590 in my copy) contains a lot of stuff, while the other (line 620 in my copy) contains only the description that you're looking for. BeautifulSoup is returning the first one.

You may have better luck using `find("div", class_="product_desc")` which seems to select the element that you want.